# Getting Segmentation Fault in C program

Tags: c, arrays, pthreads, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault on line 8 in the code below.

```
typedef struct _my_struct {
     int pArr[21];      
     int arr1[8191];
     int arr2[8191];
     int m;
     int cLen;
     int gArr[53];  
     int dArr[8191]; 
     int data[4096];
     int rArr[53]; 
     int eArr[1024];

};

void *populate_data(void *arg) {
1   register int mask =1, iG;
2   struct _my_struct *var ;
3   var = arg;                         // arg is passed as initialized struct variable while creating thread
4   var->m = 13;
5   var->arr2[var->m] = 0;
6   for (iG = 0; iG < var->m; iG++) {
7       var->arr2[iG] = mask;
8       var->arr1[var->arr2[iG]] = iG;
9       if (var->pArr[iG] != 0)         // pArr[]= 1011000000001
10          var->arr2[var->m] ^= mask;
11      mask <<= 1;
12  }
13  var->arr1[var->arr2[var->m]] = var->m;
14  mask >>= 1;
15  for (iG = var->m+ 1; iG < var->cLen; iG++) {
16      if (var->arr2[iG - 1] >= mask)
17          var->arr2[iG] = var->arr2[var->m] ^ ((var->arr2[iG- 1] ^ mask) << 1);
18      else
19          var->arr2[iG] = var->arr2[iG- 1] << 1;
20      var->arr1[var->arr2[iG]] = iG;
21  }
22  var->arr1[0] = -1;
   }
```

Here is the thread function:

```
void main() {
        unsigned int tid;

        struct _my_struct  *instance = NULL;
        instance = (struct _my_struct  *)malloc(sizeof(_my_struct ));

        start_thread(&tid , 119312, populate_data, instance );          
}

int 
start_thread(unsigned int *tid, int stack_size, void * (*my_function)(void *), void *arg)
{
        pthread_t ptid = -1;
        pthread_attr_t pattrib;

        pthread_attr_init(&pattrib);

        if(stack_size > 0)
        {
            pthread_attr_setstacksize(&pattrib, stack_size);
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_attr_destroy(&pattrib);
            return -1;
        }

        pthread_create(&ptid, &pattrib, my_function, arg);      
        pthread_attr_destroy(&pattrib);

        return 0;
}
```

Once I debug it through gdb, got this error,

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffdfec80700 (LWP 22985)]
0x0000000000401034 in populate_data (arg=0x7fffffffe5d8) at Queue.c:19
19                     var->arr1[var->arr2[iG]] = iG;
```

and its backtrace is:

```
#0  0x0000000000401034 in populate_data (arg=0x7fffffffe5d8) at Queue.c:159
#1  0x00007ffff7bc6971 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff792292d in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

However, I'm unable to correct the error.

Anyhelp is really appreciated.

Comment: Displaying the values of `iG` and `var->arr2[iG]` after the seg fault might give you a clue...

Comment: It failed at first iteration i.e iG =0

Comment: OK - but what is the value of `var->arr2[0]` ?

Comment: The value `var->arr2[iG]` not within the allowed indexes for the `arr1`, hence the segfault.

Comment: What is `var->cLen` in line 15? Can't find such a struct member.

Comment: @Sergey L. The value of var->cLen is 4148 and missed in the struct.

Comment: @PaulR: when I do **print var->arr2[iG]** where iG=0, it says **cannot access memory at address 0x8000003fe650**

Comment: @axiom: Its working perfectly fine when I have global variables instead of struct. No idea why do I have seg fault now.

Comment: Is the argument that you pass to `pthread_create` on the stack or on the heap? Could it be stackspace that is deallocated?

Comment: ARE YOU SURE it's on line 8 and not on line 20 of your sample code?  They're both the same, and gdb output says it SEGV'd on line 19, which is closer to 20 than 8, just wondering.....

Comment: @SergeyL.: I passed it to the stack.

Comment: @phonetagger: There was a commented code at the time of debugging which I removed before posting here.

Comment: A couple of questions: Why do you even typedef the struct when you still use `struct _my_struct`, but you don't use `sizeof(struct _my_struct)` for malloc? As someone pointed out you should probably use `calloc` in this case or make sure to `memset` it to 0.

Comment: Actually I don't even get how it compiles with `sizeof(_my_struct)`..

Comment: ...yeah.  When I built it, I had to change it to _my_struct_t (which I added as the name of the typedef, see my post).

Answer (score 1):

Please show the calling code in `start_thread`.

It seems likely to be a stack and/or memory allocation error, the structure is pretty large (8 MB assuming 32-bit `int`s) and might well overflow some stack limit.

Even more possible is that it's gone out of scope, which is why the calling step must be shown.

Comment: added it the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if perhaps you've changed the names of the arrays in your _my_struct in order to hide the purpose of them (company confidential information, perhaps?), but if that's actually what you've named your arrays, I'm just going to suggest that you name them something that makes sense to you that when someone has to read your code 4 years from now, they'll have some hope of following your initialization loops & understanding what's going on.  Same goes for your loop variable `iG`.

My next comment/question is, why are you firing off a thread to initialize this structure that's on the stack of the main thread?  Which thread is going to be using this structure once it's initialized?  Or are you going to make other threads that will use it?  Do you have any mechanism (mutex? semaphore?) to ensure that the other threads won't start using the data until your initialization thread is done initializing it?  Which sort of begs the question, why the heck are you bothering to fire off a separate thread to initialize it in the first place; you could just initialize it by calling populate_data() straight from main() and not even have to worry about synchronization because you wouldn't even be starting up any other threads until after it's done being initialized.  If you're running on a multicore machine, you might get some small benefit from firing off that separate thread to do the initialization while main() goes on & does other stuff, but from the size of your struct (not tiny, but not huge either) it seems like that benefit would be very miniscule.  And if you're running on a single core, you'll get no concurrency benefit at all; you'd just be wasting time firing off another thread to do it due to the context switching overhead; in a unicore environment you'd be better off just calling populate_data() directly from main().

Next comment is, your _my_struct is not huge, so it's not going to blow your stack by itself.  But it ain't tiny either.  If your app will always need only one copy of this struct, maybe you should make it a global variable or a file-scope variable, so it doesn't eat up stack space.

Finally, to your actual bug............

I didn't bother to try to decipher your cryptic looping code, but valgrind is telling me that you have some conditions that depend on uninitialized locations:

```
~/test/so$ valgrind a.out
==27663== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27663== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27663== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27663== Command: a.out
==27663==
==27663== Thread 2:
==27663== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==27663==    at 0x8048577: populate_data (so2.c:34)
==27663==    by 0x593851: start_thread (in /lib/libpthread-2.5.so)
==27663==    by 0x4BDA8D: clone (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==27663==
==27663== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==27663==    at 0x804868A: populate_data (so2.c:40)
==27663==    by 0x593851: start_thread (in /lib/libpthread-2.5.so)
==27663==    by 0x4BDA8D: clone (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
```

My so2.c line 34 corresponds with line 9 in your code posting above.
My so2.c line 40 corresponds with line 15 in your code posting above.

If I add the following at the top of populate_data(), these valgrind errors disappear:

```
memset(arg,0,sizeof(_my_struct_t));
```

(I modified your struct definition as follows:)

```
typedef struct _my_struct { int pArr[21]; ......... } _my_struct_t;
```

Now just because adding the memset() call makes the errors disappear doesn't necessarily mean that your loop logic is correct, it just means that now those locations are considered "initialized" by valgrind.  If having all-zeros in those locations when your initialization loops begin is what your logic needs, then that should fix it.  But you need to verify for yourself that such really is the proper solution.

BTW... someone suggested using calloc() to get a zeroed-out allocation (rather than using dirty stack space)... that would work too, but if you want populate_data() to be foolproof, you'll zero the memory in it and not in the caller, since (assuming you like your initialization logic as it is), populate_data() is the thing that depends on it being zeroed out, main() shouldn't have to care whether it is or not.  Not a biggie either way.